# Using XMLReader to parse deeply nested value quickly

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xmlreader

I am new to XMLReader and I want to extract some deeply nested nodes. I am unable to grab the values I wanted. Below I have an example of the element I am parsing, the code I am using, and what value I want. Link to xml file: http://datastore.unm.edu/schedules/current.xml

XML element:

```
<unmschedule version="1.0.4" pubdate="2016-10-30-13:00:02" source="UNM">
<usage>
  <guideline url="http://xmlschedule.unm.edu/docs/xml-schedule-usage-guideline.html"/>
</usage>
<lookups>
  <parts-of-term>...</parts-of-term>
  <statuses>...</statuses>
</lookups>
<semester code="201680" name="Fall 2016" index="1">
  <campus code="ABQ" name="Albuquerque/Main">
    <college code="AP" name="School of Arch. and Planning">
      <department code="ABM" name="School Architecture Planning">
        <subject code="ARCH" name="Architecture">
          <course number="109" title="Design Fundamentals">
        <catalog-description>
         Studio/lecture.
        </catalog-description>
        <section crn="41646" number="002" part-of-term="1" status="S">
          <section-title/>
          <text>Cancel/Reschedule to CRN 57664 04/20/2016.</text>
          <instructional-method code=""/>
          <delivery-type code="LC">Lecture</delivery-type>
          <enrollment max="18">0</enrollment>
          <waitlist max="0">0</waitlist>
          <credits>3</credits>
        </section>
        <section crn="45817" number="008" part-of-term="1" status="A">
          <section-title/>
          <text/>
          <instructional-method code="ENH">Web Enhanced</instructional-method>
          <delivery-type code="LC">Lecture</delivery-type>
```

Code:

```
$map_url = 'http://datastore.unm.edu/schedules/current.xml'; 

$xml = new XMLReader;
$xml->open($map_url);

$xml->read();

while ($xml->read()) {
    if ($xml->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT) {
            print $xml->semester->campus->college->department->subject->course.': ';
    } else if ($xml->nodeType == XMLReader::TEXT) {
            print $xml->semester->campus->college->department->subject->course->value.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Nodes I want to extract:

1) In the `<course>` tag I want the "number" and "title" e.g. 109 and Design Fundamentals.

2) In the `<section>` tag I want the "crn" and number e.g. 41646 and 002

Comment: do you require xmlreader for that?

Comment: @Dekel - I just need something that parses fast.